# How to fix skewed image for OCR?

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv

I just started OCR project a few weeks ago. I stuck with image skewed problem I tried many different methods nothing seems to work so plz help:)

Skewed image given below

[image: skewed image link]

I want final image such as given below

[image: final image as required]

I already tried to deskew image but I was unable to get final image.

```
public Image<Gray, byte> ImageDeskewOuter(Image<Gray, byte> img)
{
    img = img.Resize(img.Height, img.Width, Inter.Linear);
    Image<Gray, byte> tmp = new Image<Gray, byte>(img.Bitmap);
    tmp = tmp.ThresholdToZero(new Gray(180));

    int nZero = tmp.CountNonzero()[0] == 0 ? 1 : tmp.CountNonzero()[0];
    if (tmp.Bytes.Length / nZero < 10)
        img = tmp.Not();
    else
        img = img.ThresholdToZero(new Gray(80)).InRange(new Gray(0), new Gray(60)).Not();
    tmp = new Image<Gray, byte>(img.Bitmap).Canny(50, 150);

    List<Rectangle> rlist = new List<Rectangle>();
    Rectangle min = new Rectangle();
    Rectangle max = new Rectangle();
    VectorOfVectorOfPoint contour = new VectorOfVectorOfPoint();
    Mat hier = new Mat();
    CvInvoke.FindContours(tmp, contour, hier, RetrType.External, ChainApproxMethod.ChainApproxSimple);
    if (contour.Size > 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < contour.Size; i++)
        {
            Rectangle rec = CvInvoke.BoundingRectangle(contour[i]);
            if (rec.Width > 30 && rec.Width < 120 && rec.Height > 50 && rec.Height < 120)
            {
                rlist.Add(rec);                        
            }
        }
        min = rlist.OrderBy(x => x.X).FirstOrDefault();
        max = rlist.OrderByDescending(x => x.X).FirstOrDefault();
        Rectangle roi = Rectangle.Union(min, max);
        img.ROI = roi;
    }
    if (rlist.Count > 0)
    {
        double angle = LineAngle(min.X, min.Bottom, max.X, max.Bottom, min.X, min.Bottom, max.X, min.Bottom) + 3;
        img = img.Rotate(angle, new Gray(255), false);
    }
    return img;
}
```

> Final image using above function

[image: my image after using above code]

Comment: #Gimby, As I explained above that I want deskew image, plz focus on that do not jump on next step and perform OCR...:)

Comment: What libraries are you using?

Comment: EmguCV.3.1.0.1 with tesseract

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 > Select desired contour and apply CvInvoke.MinAreaRect() and copy image area into new image

Step 2> Create a bitmap image whose width is sum of all cropped image width(if you want to put each image side by side)

Step 3> Using Graphics draw image on bitmap

```
    public Image<Gray, byte> ImageDeskew(Image<Gray, byte> img)
    {
        img = img.Resize(img.Height, img.Width, Inter.Linear);
        Image<Gray, byte> tmp = new Image<Gray, byte>(img.Bitmap);
        tmp = new Image<Gray, byte>(AdjustContrast(tmp.Bitmap, 70));

        img = tmp.Not().ThresholdAdaptive(new Gray(255), AdaptiveThresholdType.MeanC, ThresholdType.Binary, 45, new Gray(10));
        tmp = new Image<Gray, byte>(img.Bitmap).Canny(50, 150);

         List<Image<Gray, byte>> imglist = new List<Image<Gray, byte>>();
        Rectangle min = new Rectangle();
        Rectangle max = new Rectangle();
        VectorOfVectorOfPoint contour = new VectorOfVectorOfPoint();
        Mat hier = new Mat();
        CvInvoke.FindContours(tmp, contour, hier, RetrType.External, ChainApproxMethod.ChainApproxSimple);
        if (contour.Size > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < contour.Size; i++)
            {
                RotatedRect rRect = CvInvoke.MinAreaRect(contour[i]);
                float area = rRect.Size.Width * rRect.Size.Height;
                if (area > (img.Bytes.Length / 10))
                {
                    rlist.Add(rec);
                    if (rRect.Angle > -45) imglist.Add(img.Copy(rRect));
                    else imglist.Add(img.Copy(rRect).Rotate(-90, new Gray(255), false));
                }                    
            }
        }

       
            if (imglist.Count > 0)
            {
                int xPx = imglist.Sum(x => x.Width);
                Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(xPx, img.Height);
                using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
                {
                    xPx = 0;
                    imglist.Reverse();
                    foreach (Image<Gray, byte> i in imglist)
                    {
                        g.DrawImage(i.Not().Bitmap, xPx, 0);
                        xPx += i.Width;
                    }
                }
                img = new Image<Gray, byte>(bitmap).Not();
            }
        
        return img;
    }
```